# overridding string with var-args

Tags: java, oop, methods, overriding, variadic-functions

Generally Var arg method override with same method  var arg method but in my code normal method override with var args.

But In general Var args methods should only override or be overridden by other var args methods unlike `Test.go(String[])` and `A.go(String...)`.

but I have gotten output T.

```
class A{
    public void go(String...s){
            System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class Test extends A {

    public void go(String[] a){
        System.out.println("T");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        A a = new Test();

        a.go("dd");
    }
}
```

output: T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String[]` and `String...` are equivalent is some cases, so `go(String... s)` can be overriden by `go(String[] s)`. It's one of the ways to indicate array in java.

Comment: "equivalent" *almost*. You can invoke a varargs method with an explicit array, but not the other way around.

Comment: this is working on 1.8 version similarly it also working on 1.7 or 1.6 as well

Answer (score 1):

Varargs is just syntactic sugaring for an array of the same type that indicates to the compiler that the series of comma-delimited arguments from this point on should be treated as an array. From a signature's perspective, `String[]` and `String...` are the same. For example, you could define your main method as `public static void main(String... args)` if you want.

Comment: this is working on 1.8 version similarly it also working on 1.7 or 1.6 as well

Answer (score 0):

Both declarations are equivalent as Java compiler expands varargs to array of specified type. 
So you have effectively overridden `go` method.

take look at https://www.journaldev.com/1257/java-varargs#how-java-varargs-work